# Alternatives to google static maps

Tags: cdn, google-maps

Goood Day

Essentially I am getting hammered with costs for google static maps as I have a reasonably high traffic website and need to place a static map image on many of the web pages. Google want to start charging me $1500 a month for this now.

The problem is I could quite easily cache static map tiles in our CDN and eliminate the costs but this is explicitly against googles Ts&Cs.

Are there other services available that provide the same service as google static maps at reasonable costs AND allow caching static maps tiles?

Comment: Could you describe what you understand under "the same service as google static maps"? What are the features/requirements?

Comment: @unor Requesting an image with custom dimensions which is centred at a particular latitude & longitude. I don't actually need any customization of the map beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use maps from the [OpenStreetMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap) project? The data is free/libre (licensed under [Open Database License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_License)).

See the documentation about [how to use the maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap#Maps). There are various [frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) available.

If you don’t find a hosting service that suits your needs, you could even [host the data yourself](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data).